# HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Could not initialize proxy AFTER adding data into DB

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Here's my question. I am unable to write the JSON after I send a `POST` request from POSTMAN to create/add a row into my SQL database. I need the server to send back a response of the added entry in order to retrieve the ID that SQL generates.

I face this issue when the new `Case` entry is a child of two entities(`User` and `Application`) and a grandchild of one entity(`Owner`).

```
*User(Owner)
|\
| *Application
|/ 
*Case
```

I'm new and currently using the Spring Boot JPA package.

I'm aware that many have asked questions related to the error above. There is none regarding my case to my knowledge. All of them refer to fixes over a HTTP `GET` method. If you found some please guide me to them. Or please help to answer my query. Any help is appreciated!

I attach my codes here:

User Entity

```
    package com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities;
    import javax.persistence.*;
    @Entity(name = "User")
    @Table(name = "User", schema = "dbo")
    public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String staffId;

    private String username;

    private String role;

    public User (){}

    public User(Integer id, String staffId, String username, String role) {
        this.id = id;
        this.staffId = staffId;
        this.username = username;
        this.role = role;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
    }
```

Application Entity

```
    package com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities;
    import javax.persistence.*;
    @Entity(name = "Application")
    @Table(name = "InvApplication", schema = "dbo")
    public class Application {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String applicationName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ownerId")
    private User owner;

    public Application(){}

    public Application(Integer id, String applicationName, User owner) {
        this.id = id;
        this.applicationName = applicationName;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
    }
```

Case Entity

```
package com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities;

import com.lightlce.CRUD.AuditModel.Auditable;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "Case")
@Table(name = "InvCase", schema = "dbo")
public class Case extends Auditable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "applicationId")
    private Application application;

    //redacted

    public Case() {
    }

    public Case(Integer id, User user, Application application) {
        this.id = id;
        this.user = user;
        this.application = application;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Case Controller

```
package com.lightlce.CRUD.Controllers;

import com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.Application;
import com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.Case;
import com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.User;
import com.lightlce.CRUD.Repository.ApplicationRepository;
import com.lightlce.CRUD.Repository.CaseRepository;
import com.lightlce.CRUD.Repository.UserRepository;
import com.lightlce.CRUD.Services.ApplicationService;
import com.lightlce.CRUD.Services.CaseService;
import com.lightlce.CRUD.Services.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
public class CaseController {

    @Autowired
    private CaseService caseService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationRepository applicationRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CaseRepository caseRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserController userController;

    @RequestMapping("cases")
    public Page<Case> getAllCases(Pageable pageable) {
        return caseService.getAllCases(pageable);
    }

    @PostMapping("cases/add")
    public Case addCase(@RequestBody Case aCase) {
        User staff = userService.searchUser(aCase.getUser()); //Finds the user based on ID provided
        Application application = applicationRepository.findById(aCase.getApplication().getId()).get(); //Finds the application based on ID provided
        aCase.setUser(staff);
        aCase.setApplication(application);
        return caseService.addCase(aCase);
    }
}
```

Case Service

```
package com.lightlce.CRUD.Services;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.Application;
import com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.Case;
import com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.User;
import com.lightlce.CRUD.Repository.CaseRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CaseService {

    @Autowired
    private CaseRepository caseRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public Page<Case> getAllCases(Pageable pageable){
        return caseRepository.customFindAll(pageable);
    }

    public Case addCase(Case aCase) {
        caseRepository.save(aCase);
        return aCase;
    }
}
```

Case Repository

```
package com.lightlce.CRUD.Repository;

import com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.Case;
import com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.User;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface CaseRepository extends JpaRepository<Case, Integer>{
    Page<Case> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    @Query(value = "SELECT c FROM com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.Case c " +
            "JOIN FETCH c.user u " +
            "JOIN FETCH c.application a " +
            "JOIN FETCH a.owner o",
            countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(c) FROM  com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.Case c " +
                    "JOIN c.user u " +
                    "JOIN c.application a " +
                    "JOIN a.owner o")
    Page<Case> customFindAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

POST http://localhost:8080/cases/add

```
{
    "user": {
        "staffId": "TEST123"
    },
    "application":{
        "id": 2
    }
}
```

Expected Response

```
{
      "created_at": "2020-05-13T09:34:04.093+0000",
      "modified_at": "2020-05-13T09:34:04.093+0000",
      "id": 1
      "user": {
             "id": 1,
             "staffId": "TEST123",
             "username": "lightlce",
             "role": "admin"
      },
      "application": {
             "id": 2,
             "applicationName": "ApplicationDemo",
             "owner": {
                 "id": 1,
                 "staffId": "TEST123",
                 "username": "lightlce",
                 "role": "admin"
             }
      }
}
```

Postman Exception

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-05-14T02:36:40.999+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy [com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.User#2] - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy [com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.User#2] - no Session (through reference chain: com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.Case[\"application\"]->com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.Application[\"owner\"]->com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.User$HibernateProxy$QRpaILkJ[\"staffId\"])",
    "path": "/cases/add"
}
```

Springboot Logs

```
2020-05-14 10:36:38.262 DEBUG 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_0_,
        user0_.role as role2_0_,
        user0_.staffId as staffId3_0_,
        user0_.username as username4_0_ 
    from
        dbo.InvAllUser user0_ 
    where
        user0_.staffId=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_0_,
        user0_.role as role2_0_,
        user0_.staffId as staffId3_0_,
        user0_.username as username4_0_ 
    from
        dbo.InvAllUser user0_ 
    where
        user0_.staffId=?
2020-05-14 10:36:38.278 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [TEST123]
2020-05-14 10:36:38.808 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [1]
2020-05-14 10:36:38.811 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([role2_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [admin]
2020-05-14 10:36:38.812 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([staffId3_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [TEST123]
2020-05-14 10:36:38.812 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([username4_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [lightlce]
2020-05-14 10:36:38.837 DEBUG 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        applicatio0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        applicatio0_.applicationName as applicat2_1_0_,
        applicatio0_.ownerId as ownerId3_1_0_ 
    from
        dbo.InvApplication applicatio0_ 
    where
        applicatio0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        applicatio0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        applicatio0_.applicationName as applicat2_1_0_,
        applicatio0_.ownerId as ownerId3_1_0_ 
    from
        dbo.InvApplication applicatio0_ 
    where
        applicatio0_.id=?
2020-05-14 10:36:38.839 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [2]
2020-05-14 10:36:39.427 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([applicat2_1_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [ApplicationDemo]
2020-05-14 10:36:39.427 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([ownerId3_1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [2]
2020-05-14 10:36:39.546 DEBUG 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    insert 
    into
        dbo.InvCase
        (created_at, modified_at, applicationId, approverId, caseDesc, caseTitle, caseType, status, userId) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        dbo.InvCase
        (created_at, modified_at, applicationId, approverId, caseDesc, caseTitle, caseType, status, userId) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-05-14 10:36:39.553 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Thu May 14 10:36:39 SGT 2020]
2020-05-14 10:36:39.555 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Thu May 14 10:36:39 SGT 2020]
2020-05-14 10:36:39.555 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [2]
2020-05-14 10:36:39.555 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2020-05-14 10:36:39.555 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [ApplicationDemo]
2020-05-14 10:36:39.555 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [TEST123]
2020-05-14 10:36:39.555 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [7] as [VARCHAR] - [new]
2020-05-14 10:36:39.556 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [8] as [VARCHAR] - [Pending]
2020-05-14 10:36:39.557 TRACE 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [9] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2020-05-14 10:36:40.987  WARN 50878 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy [com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.User#2] - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy [com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.User#2] - no Session (through reference chain: com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.Case["application"]->com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.Application["owner"]->com.lightlce.CRUD.Entities.User$HibernateProxy$QRpaILkJ["staffId"])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this workaround.

Since `fooService.save(foo);` also updates the `foo` object with the ID, I can simply `return foo.getId()` to achieve what I want without sending another find method.

i.e. Case Service

```
public Integer updateCase(Case aCase) {
        caseRepository.save(aCase);
        return aCase.getId();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are as many problems with your code as i really don't know how to help to solve it.
but as a quick fix try to create a new entity class for user object.

Comment: I still face this issue. I think the issue here is with the grandchild element of `Case` to `User`. The custom query works when I use the `GET` method. I could run the same custom Query on the POST element.. but I am not sure if that is good for performance. Thank you for your suggestion. Perhaps you can point me to the problems you identified in my code separately.